# How to troubleshoot the installation for DSX Local?

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-local

The installation for DSX-Local keeps failing on step 32.
I tried with new installations both for RHEL 7.4 and CentOS

It seems the error is somehow related to the network - not %100 sure. The cloudant and redis pods show a imagepullback status.

I tried multiple things - but always fails on step 32. I believe maybe it has to do with the network between the nodes (inside VirtualBox on a host-only network), but not sure.

How to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before answer the question, I think you need to provide more information about the installation you have - 1 node or 3/9 node? What is the version? What architecture?

The cluster will have its own docker registry setup, Tag the image with localhost:5000/ and then push, then it will pushing to that registry. Back to your question, if you see pods are "imagepullback", then probably not able to pull from the registry.

You can use curl http://:5000/v2/_catalog to see if you can query the registry to make sure it is working properly